# OpenCV Draw line dynamically on image

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I’m hoping someone can help me. I am creating a c++ program which allows the user to draw a line on an image that has been captured by a camera. I am using QT and can get the user to draw a line however; I want to see the line as it is being drawn by the user. Currently my program only allows the user to see the line at the point the mouse is clicked and when the mouse is released. I want the program to display the line as it is being drawn.

I have posted my code below

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <QString>

#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>


#include "ueye.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


HIDS hCam = 0;      // 0 for the next available camera. 1-254 to access by ID
SENSORINFO sInfo;
HWND hWndDisplay;

char* pcImageMemory;
int DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight;

cv::Point P3;
cv::Point P4;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
cout << "Lets Begin" << endl;
CaptureImage();
//Timer = new QTimer(this);
//connect(Timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(DisplayImage()));
//Timer->start(); //Will start the timer
ui->display_image->setMouseTracking(true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{



    delete ui;

}

void MainWindow::CaptureImage(){
    cout << "Capture Image" << endl;
    is_InitCamera(&hCam, hWndDisplay);

    // You can query information about the sensor type used in the camera
    is_GetSensorInfo(hCam, &sInfo);

    // Saving the information about the max. image proportions in variables
    DisplayWidth = sInfo.nMaxWidth;
    DisplayHeight = sInfo.nMaxHeight;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Need to find out the memory size of the pixel and the colour mode
    int nColorMode;
    int nBitsPerPixel = 24;

    if (sInfo.nColorMode == IS_COLORMODE_BAYER)
    {
        // For color camera models use RGB24 mode
        nColorMode = IS_CM_BGR8_PACKED;
        nBitsPerPixel = 24;
    }
    else if (sInfo.nColorMode == IS_COLORMODE_CBYCRY)
    {
        // For CBYCRY camera models use RGB32 mode
        nColorMode = IS_CM_BGRA8_PACKED;
        nBitsPerPixel = 32;
    }
    else
    {
        // For monochrome camera models use Y8 mode
        nColorMode = IS_CM_MONO8;
        nBitsPerPixel = 24;
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    int nMemoryId;

    // Assigns a memory for the image and sets it active
    is_AllocImageMem(hCam, DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight, nBitsPerPixel, &pcImageMemory, &nMemoryId);
    is_SetImageMem(hCam, pcImageMemory, nMemoryId);

    // Acquires a single image from the camera
    is_FreezeVideo(hCam, IS_WAIT);

    // Parameter definition for saving the image file
    IMAGE_FILE_PARAMS ImageFileParams;
    ImageFileParams.pwchFileName = L"./TestImage.bmp";   /// <-- Insert name and location of the image
    ImageFileParams.pnImageID = NULL;
    ImageFileParams.ppcImageMem = NULL;
    ImageFileParams.nQuality = 0;
    ImageFileParams.nFileType = IS_IMG_BMP;

    // Saves the image file
    if (is_ImageFile(hCam, IS_IMAGE_FILE_CMD_SAVE, (void*)&ImageFileParams, sizeof(ImageFileParams)) == IS_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "An Image was saved" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "something went wrong" << endl;
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Releases an image memory that was allocated
    is_FreeImageMem(hCam, pcImageMemory, nMemoryId);

    // Disables the hCam camera handle and releases the data structures and memory areas taken up by the uEye camera
    is_ExitCamera(hCam);


    //return -1;
    DisplayImage();
}


void MainWindow::DisplayImage(){
cout << "Display image" << endl;



//cv::Point p1(100,100), p2(200,100);

   cv::Scalar colorLine(0,255,0); // Green
   int thicknessLine = 2;

    Mat img;
    img = imread("./TestImage.bmp");
    cv::resize(img, img, Size(861, 530), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR);
    cv::cvtColor(img,img,cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR); //Qt reads in RGB whereas CV in BGR
    //cout << P3 << endl;
    cv::line(img, P3, P4, colorLine, thicknessLine);
    QImage imdisplay((uchar*)img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888); //Converts the CV image into Qt standard format
    ui->display_image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imdisplay));//display the image in label that is created earlier

}


void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
  //qDebug() << "Mouse move.." << event->pos() << "---> " << event->pos().x() << "," << event->pos().y(); // these printing same values

}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
  qDebug() << "Mouse press.." << event->pos() << "---> " << event->pos().x() << "," << event->pos().y(); // these printing same values
  P3 = cv::Point(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());
}

void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << "Mouse release.." << event->pos() << "---> " << event->pos().x() << "," << event->pos().y(); // these printing same values
P4 = cv::Point(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());
DisplayImage();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Well you need to move your line drawing code to `mouseMoveEvent`, have you tried that? You will also need to erase the previously drawn line before drawing the new line.

Comment: Thanks john by adding my code `P4 = cv::Point(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());` and then adding `DisplayImage();` to the `mouseMoveEvent` Worked. Thanks again